# Why two-point blow up of $CP^2$ can be diffeomorphic to blow up of $S^2 \times S^2$?

Tags: differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

> Why two-point blow up of $CP^2$ can be diffeomorphic to blow up of $S^2 \times S^2$?

We may consider their intersection form and see that they are homeomorphoc, but is there any explicit construction of diffeomorphism?

Comment: Just as you do not starting writing an email in the subject line (I hope!) you do not put the question in the title.

Comment: Adding on to @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez comment, your title should be a brief, but informative description of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!